# In Chrome DevTools, can I turn off stacking of console.log messages?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have Javascript code that loops through an array, and I have some quick console.log() calls that either prints "Not found" or "Found!" as the loop examines each element in the array for something.

I noticed that in the Chrome DevTools console tab, it stacks thee same console.log message together.  For example, if the first 4 iterations of the loop result in "Not found" the console tab shows:

```
(4) Not found
```

Is there any way to see the console.log message as separate lines?

Comment: Why do you want this? The easiest way would be to change your code to say which element wasn't found, like `0: Not found`, `1: Not found`, etc. It also makes your logging clearer.

Comment: Well, I came from Firebug and it always listed out the console.log() message sequentially.  I'm used to seeing code executed in sequential order.  I don't like how Chrome DevTools bundles the same message and rolls them up into one line.

Comment: Well in my experience, the bundling is a godsend. It makes it much easier and faster to find the lines which are different, and means you can do silly things like log within a frequent event (like a mouse move or interval) and you'll only actually see anything as the value changes. Anyway I'm not aware of a way to disable it, so making the error messages subtly different is probably the way to go. (personally I find the chrome developer tools to be far superior to firebug, but I guess that comes down to personal preference. Take some time to get used to them and you might like them too)

Comment: The obvious (and brute-force) solution is to add a timestamp/random number at the end of each "Not Found"/"Found" message.

Comment: That is what Dave suggested as well.  I will go with this idea.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked ages ago, but to anyone who finds this, the quickest and easiest way to do this is to add a TimeStamp to the log:

```
console.log("Found:" + new Date());
```

Comment: Actually it´s a way to bypass the similar lines collapsing feature.

Comment: Ewan's answer is OK in terms of trying to answer my original question.  It's an alternative to the other comments above.  Putting the loop counter as suggested by others is arguably better, since it tells me the program state at that loop iteration.  A timestamp is a little less helpful, but it does get around the console message bundling.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with "Group similar messages in console" checkbox in console settings.

[image]